# How to escape slash in URL parameter

Tags: javascript, php

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/v1/cases/annotations/" + case_id + "/" + encodeURIComponent(current_plink),
```

I am using **encodeURIComponent** to escape slash. But it does not work for me. This code convert "slash" to "%2F" but apache does not recognize it.

My php part like this :

```
$app->get('/cases/annotations/:case_id/:prep_name', 'authenticatePathologist', function($case_id, $prep_name) use ($app) {
```

If i try to send parameter which include slash, it returns page not found.
[image]

But if i try to send parameter which does not include slash, it returns OK.
[image]

Comment: why not `+current_plink` ?

Comment: Maybe try double encoding with `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: @Gothdo it works, interesting. Do you have any idea about why ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should encode it twice with `encodeURIComponent`, i.e. `encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(current_plink))`. If you encode it only once, the server decodes it, and it's the same as not encoding it at all.

Answer (score 0):

you should follow
[AllowEncodedSlashes Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes)

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar issue with url like:

```
?filters=new:item:text
```

where it required to escape the colons. for that I tried replacing it to format
`?filters/:items/:text` but that couldn't work as the Chrome was NOT encoding the '/' value.

Tried the js **`[escape() method][1]`** and it worked like charm.

```
let url = 'https://dev.test.something?filters=';
let filterString = 'new:item:text';
url = url + escape(filterString);
```

**Output:**

```
https://dev.test.something?filters=new%3Aitem%3Atext
```

Hope this finds helpful!!

Comment: `escape()` is deprecated